# Get status of Matplotlib radio button

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Using Matplotlib, I can get the value of a Slider widget by using "mySlider.val", which is very convenient. Is there an equivalent capability to get the current selection of a Radio Button? I think that this question is what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778441/get-python-matplotlib-radiobutton-selection) was trying to ask, but the asker did not provide a working example. I provide the following example, indicating the missing line of code that I am looking for.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons, Button, Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axSlider = plt.axes([0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.05])
aSlider  = Slider(axSlider,'A slider', 0,1,  valinit=0.5)

axRadio  = plt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
butRadio = RadioButtons(axRadio, ('Top','Middle','Bottom'))

axStatus = plt.axes([0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
bStatus  = Button(axStatus,'Get status of radio buttons')

def get_status(val):
    #radioValue = ???? -- Need this line of code.
    radioValue = 0
    sliderValue= aSlider.val
    print 'Slider value: %.2f, Radio button value: %.2f'%(sliderValue,radioValue)

bStatus.on_clicked(get_status)
plt.show()
```

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

If this is not possible, can you suggest an elegant work-around? Currently I am using the "on_clicked" function for the Radio Buttons and setting global variables with the values of the radio buttons, and this is messy.

Comment: If you look at the source for `RadioButtons` it does not keep track of this.  You just need to add an instance attribute for the currently active button and update it in `_clicked` (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L610) This seems like a feature it _should_ have and a PR to add it would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added two lines of code to widgets.py that seems to accomplish this goal. Specifically, I added `self.val = t.get_text()` to the `_clicked` function and `self.val = label` to the `__init__` function. I created a pull request of the matplotlib github, but this is the first time that I have done this, so hopefully I did it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @tcaswell, I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3971#issuecomment-69268762) to matplotlib on github and now it is possible to query the current status of the RadioButtons. The missing line of code is:

```
radioValue = butRadio.value_selected
```

<s>This is scheduled to be incorporated into the 1.5.x release of matplotlib. In the mean time, if you want to use this feature, you will need to download the development release of [matplotlib from github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) (or, at least download the 'widgets.py' file).</s>

This is now incorporated into the current release of Matplotlib (1.5.3). (See the [Widets Docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html).) If this above line doesn't work, you can likely just update Matplotlib.

Comment: This is merged and will be released with 1.5 (coming 'soon').

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest answer is:**

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons, Button, Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axSlider = plt.axes([0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.05])
aSlider  = Slider(axSlider,'A slider', 0,1,  valinit=0.5)

axRadio  = plt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
my_list = ('Top','Middle','Bottom')
butRadio = RadioButtons(axRadio, my_list)

axStatus = plt.axes([0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
bStatus  = Button(axStatus,'Get status of radio buttons')

def activated_radio_button(x,list):     
    for i in xrange(len(x.circles)):
                if x.circles[i].get_facecolor()[0]<.5:
                    return list[i]

def get_status(label):
    radioValue = activated_radio_button(butRadio,my_list)
    sliderValue= aSlider.val
    print 'Slider value: %.2f, Radio button value: %s'%(sliderValue,radioValue)

bStatus.on_clicked(get_status)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this post doing research on the same issue.  They haven't made any update to matplotlib yet, though I did find a related post on retrieving the value from matplotlib's checkbuttons here:  [Retrieving the selected values from a CheckButtons object in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812938/retrieving-the-selected-values-from-a-checkbuttons-object-in-matplotlib)

To summarize the answer, is to keep a `dict` in which you store a variable for each button.  Whenever the button is pressed, have the event handler change the necessary values in the `dict`, which could then be accessed by other functions as needed instead of the values being trapped within just the event handler.

Hope this helps!  I know I'd rather not play around with matplotlib's source code

Comment: I'm sure it isn't, but I know that at my noobish level with Python, I'd rather not touch it, so maybe my answer will help others at my level.  Now I just wish they'd add some kind of drop down menu to matplotlib...